# What is the logic behind "prop: props[ i % props.length] inside a .map()"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

I am trying to understand...

```
// group is an array of numbers coming from an api

const arr = group.map((el, i) => {
  return new obj({
    element: el,
    prop: props[i % props.length],
  });
});
```

## Specifically

- What `props[i % props.length]` does?
- What `prop` will get in the final?

Comment: What is `group`?

Comment: It's a way to circularly repeat the `props` among `group` items. If `props` is say `[1,2,3]` and group has 9 items, the output array of objects would have `prop:1`, `prop:2`, `prop:3`, `prop:1` again etc

Comment: man, arrays interating inside themselves? I am really dumb then, because I really don't know what `i % props.length` is doing at all... at least I know that probably is a number to be used as index but this `% props.length` is the part that I really don't know what is doing there.. probably some crazy math stuff...

Comment: @VokzGnakx There is no _iteration_ inside the `map`. It's a direct `O(1)` indexer getter invocation.

Comment: @Dai, yep, you're right. I deleted my comments too, in order to avoid confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `%` operator is JavaScript's syntax for the mathematical Remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) - it's often referred to as the "modulo" operator but this is *technically incorrect* because "remainder" and "modulo" are different when dealing with negative numbers.

But in this case, we're dealing with positive array indexes, so "modulo" and "remainder" are interchangable.

"x mod y" - or "The *Modulo* of x over y" can be described as "The remainder of x divided by y". In programming this is used for many things, but in this case it's to get a valid index into `props` from `i` (where `i` is an index into `groups`, and **not** `props` - so `i` cannot be used to index `props` directly).

---

The `i` parameter is in the range of `[0-groups.length]` (i.e. **not** `props.length`!), while `props` presumably has a `props.length` that's smaller than `groups.length`.

So if you have:

```
const groups = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ]; // length: 6
const props  = [ 0, 1, 2 ]; // length: 3
```

Then the output will be:

```
const arr = [
    { el: 'a', prop: 0 },        // i = 0, i % 3 == 0
    { el: 'b', prop: 1 },        // i = 1, i % 3 == 1
    { el: 'c', prop: 2 },        // i = 2, i % 3 == 2
    { el: 'd', prop: 0 },        // i = 3, i % 3 == 0
    { el: 'e', prop: 1 },        // i = 4, i % 3 == 1
    { el: 'f', prop: 2 },        // i = 5, i % 3 == 2
];
```

---

As an aside, I die inside somewhat whenever I see someone use the identifier `props` in JavaScript. I know it's a *term of art* in the React ecosystem, but it's still... horrible.

Comment: You know sometimes we can get some crazy breeze with JS... Haha, thanks for clarify this, now I understand! @Dai

Comment: Was not aware of the differences between remainder and modulo. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @jBuchholz Any technologist on the spectrum (myself included) knows that being _technically correct_ is [the best kind of correct](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo)!

Answer (score -1):

To simplify understanding

```
i % props.length

// 0 % 8 === 0
// 1 % 8 === 1
// 2 % 8 === 2
// 3 % 8 === 3
// 4 % 8 === 4
// 5 % 8 === 5
// 6 % 8 === 6
// 7 % 8 === 7
// 8 % 8 === 0 - never gets here.
```

```
props[0]
props[1]
props[2]
props[3]
props[4]
props[5]
props[6]
props[7]
```

It might has well just been written as :

```
const arr = group.map((el, i) => new obj({
  element: el,
  prop: props[i]
}));
```

Comment: We don't know **what** `props.length` is - nor `group.length`. Your answer is only valid if `props.length === group.length` but that is not established.

Comment: Now I have got the idea, it is like circularly repeating while inside 2 lengths at the same time, cool stuff. I had never seem stuff like that. Thank you!